# Javascript class with arrays retrieving data

Tags: javascript, class

I have a javascript class like this:

```
class transportDetails{
    constructor(){
        this.car_data     = [[3,0]];  
        this.bike_data    = [[7,2]];
        this.van_data     = [[1,0]];
        this.train_data   = [[9,3]];
    }
 }

 transport = new transportDetails();
```

This is fine and works ok. But how can I perform a loop through the property names and obtain their individual values?

```
 for(n=0; n<=3; n++){
    a2 = transport.transportDetails(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(race));
 }
```

But instead of just getting the property names, i.e, car_data, bike_data etc.  I would also get the value of the two dimensional array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `transport.transportDetails` won't work, because `transport` _is_ a `transportDetails` object

Comment: `transport["car_data"]`

Answer (score 0):

Do this way :

```js
class transportDetails{
    constructor(){
        this.car_data     = [[3,0]];  
        this.bike_data    = [[7,2]];
        this.van_data     = [[1,0]];
        this.train_data   = [[9,3]];
    }
 }
 transport = new transportDetails();

 Object.keys(transport).forEach(key=>{
 console.log("key is. : ",key);
 console.log("value is. : ",transport[key]);
})
```

Comment: Many thanks that is perfect.  One quick query is how do you then get the length of the individual keys, i.e, this.train_data   = [[9,3,2,8]]; would return 3;